# CouchDB combine sorted documents to one document

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb

I have 2 documents:

1. > { path: "/monster/green", name: "Green monster", age: 105, timeline: 1 }
2. > { path: "/monster/green" name: "Really Green Monster", timeline: 2 }

The question:

How can I create a CouchDB view, where the documents are sorted by 'timeline' and the result is a combination of them:

> { path: "/monster/green", name: "Really Green Monster", age: 105 }

Comment: You'll either want to use a _list function (preferred) or a reduce (not as preferred, as you'd likely have to disable the `reduce_limit` config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a view which will give you the following output for `key="/monster/green"` :

```
{[
  {"key":"/monster/green", "value":{"name": "Green monster", "age": 105},
  {"key":"/monster/green", "value":{"name": "Really Green monster"}
]}
```

Except the format, this is really similar to the data you wanted.
If you really need to change the format, you can define a `list` on top of your `view`.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your part about the timeline... How many timelines do you have per monster? Does it worth using a reduce?